# MongoDB conifg issues at lampp ubuntu 13.04

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu, lampp

I was installing Mongodb on my Ubuntu 13.04 . It was installed and I was configured in my `php.ini` file. My OS is 32-bit version. But when I start my LAMP it show the following error.

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mongo.so' -
>   /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mongo.so:
>   undefined symbol: zend_new_interned_string in Unknown on line 0

How do i solve this?

Comment: Do you have pecl installed? You may install(compile) the php mongo extension manually if the bundled version doesn't work. (This error is most likely be caused by architecture mismatch, e.g. installing 64-bit php-mongo extension on a 32-bit php installation)

Comment: yes iam used pecl installed. how can i solve this

Comment: So you really followed the instructions on the pecl installation result output? Okay, I'm not sure but you may paste your output of `uname -m`, `file /path/to/php` and `file /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mongo.so`, this may help

Comment: No, this just provides information that helps to investigate the problem - not yet get it solved magically :)

Comment: oh! why it's happen like this i was thought the problem is the os bit version

Comment: So please provide with the output of the 3 commands above, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you compiled the extension against a different version of PHP than the binary you're attempting to load it. Assuming you followed the [PECL install instructions](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.nix), I would suggest you confirm that you only have a single copy of PHP installed on your system, and your configurations are consistent for the web and CLI environments.

Below are some previous threads and bug reports that hint to your error ("undefined symbol: zend_new_interned_string") being a PHP/extension mismatch:

- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/php-gearman-undefined-symbol-zend_new_interned_string-in-unknown-on-line-0-a-941003/
- https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/72
- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61575

The error is definitely not specific to the MongoDB driver.